# Undefined remote host when running devenv on Visual Studio for Linux project from jenkins

Tags: linux, cross-platform, visual-studio-2017, devenv, visual-c++-2017

I have a Visual Studio for Linux project. As myself, I can build it fine using **devenv** from the command line. However, when I try to run the same command from a Jenkins build, I get the error:

> There are not remote machines configured for remote builds. Please configure a 
>   machine using Tools Options / Cross Platform / Linux.

This didn't really surprise me, because the Jenkins job is running as SYSTEM, and my remote host setting is defined under my user account.

I tried copying my AppData/Local/Microsoft/Linux directory (which contains the remote host setting) to the system local appdata directory, but the remote host configuration still isn't found. Any idea how to work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found that worked was to run the Jenkins node as an actual user, one for which I had logged in and opened the Solution using VS 2017, and configured the remote host. Then the Jenkins process picked up the configuration.